# How can i insert different worksheet names into different cells horizontally with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched many times but it can't seem to find one that actually solves my question. So I have a lot of data in multiple worksheets, and they're named differently ( usually date ). I need to make all the worksheet names copied into a horizontal table but there's a catch to it. For each worksheet name I will have at least copy 5 times (in columns) before moving on to the next worksheet name. For example:

*a a a a a b b b b b c c c c c d d d d d*

*a,b,c,d* are examples of the worksheet names

Answer (score 1):

Modified an example found elsewhere. its a bit crude but should do what your asking.

```
Sub Worksheets()
     Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    For c = 1 To 5
        Worksheets(1).Cells(1, c + ((i - 1) * 5)) = Worksheets(i).Name
    Next c
    Next i    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Craig Foster for the answer.. I'm still a beginner in vba as I've never learned how to code or program, but was asked to come up with one..

Comment: is it possible that someone explain to me what does this line means? /// Worksheets(1).Cells(1, c + ((i - 1) * 5)) = Worksheets(i).Name /// i understand that Worksheets(1) means the first worksheet but i cant quite grasp the concept for the cells part